# java linked list insert from array problem

Tags: java, insert

i have a create a linkedlist class in java for a homework assignment my problem is when i try to insert numbers from another array using from loops it does not insert the numbers into my LinkedList class correctly. below is the linkedlist class

```
class LinkedList
{
    //Class variables for the Linked List
    private static Node head;
    private static int numNodes; 
    public void addAtTail(int dat)
    {
        if (head == null)
        {
            head = new Node(dat);
            numNodes++;
        }
        else
        {
            Node temp = head;
            while(temp.next != null)
            {
                temp = temp.next;
            }

            temp.next = new Node(dat);
            numNodes++;
        }
    }
    public static int getSize()
    {
        return numNodes;
    }

    class Node
    {
        //Declare class variables
        private Node next;
        private int data;

        public Node(int dat)
        {
            data = dat;
        }

        public Object getData()
        {
            return data;
        }
    }

    public static void printList()
    {
        Node temp = head;
        while(temp != null)
        {
            System.out.print(temp.data + " ");
            temp = temp.next;
        }


        System.out.println();
     }



    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int[] g = {4, 2, 3, 1, 5};
        LinkedList L = new LinkedList();

        for(int u = 0; u < g.length; u++)
            {
                L.addAtTail(g[u]);
            }


        L.printList();
    }
}
```

the code prints this out 
4 2 3 1 5 5 3 2 1 4 2 5 1 4 3 5 2 4 3 1 4 1 2 3 5 4 2 3 1 5

when it should print out just 4 2 3 1 5

Comment: I don't know how you are doing it, but I copied your code and it is printing only "4 2 3 1 5"

Comment: it does not work if the main is in another file??

Comment: It does not work if the main is in another file @RKrum

Comment: I tested in both ways previously. It is behaving the same way. You could try some debugging

Comment: Your code works as expected, just tested it out, but let me give you some advice.
You are mixing up static and non-static methods and members. You should remove your static keywords from your LinkedList class, because otherwise multiple instances of LinkedList would share the same content.
Furthermore, you could consider (for performance reasons) to keep a reference to your current tail node, so you don't spend time in a while-loop to append nodes to your LinkedList.